# Overloaded static methods not running in other class?

Tags: java, static, instance, overloading

For an exercise I am doing I have three methods, all isEven that tests a value and returns true or false. One isEven is an instance method, and the other two are static methods each with one parameter. If I make a new testClass, and run the methods in the main method the instance isEven method works fine, however when I try and use the static isEven methods I get a symbol not found error. However, if I create the main method in the actual app class and run it there the overloaded methods will work. Why is this happening? Shouldn't the static methods be able to run in another class? The methods used are below.

```
public class MyInteger {
    private int value;
    public boolean isEven() {
        if(this.value % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(value + " is an even number.");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(value + " is not an even number.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isEven(int value) {
        if(value % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(value + " is an even number.");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(value + " is not an even number.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isEven(MyInteger value) {
        if(value.value % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(value.value + " is an even number.");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(value.value + " is not an even number.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
class testMyInteger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyInteger val1 = new MyInteger(2);
        int val = 2;
        System.out.println("The value of this object is " + val1.getValu());
        val1.isEven();
        val1.isOdd();
        val1.isPrime();
        isEven(val1);
    }
}
```

Comment: just as hint: overloading static methods in java makes no sense as is not possible...

Comment: Can you add a stacktrace?

Comment: you should show us how your code looks when it's not working (having the static method in a separate class from the main). Because right now, you're just showing us code that does work so it's harder to debug.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ do you mean **overriding**? Because overloading static methods is definitely possible in Java.

Comment: yes... overriding.. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyInteger val1 = new MyInteger(2);
    int val = 2;
    System.out.println("The value of this object is " + val1.getValu());
    val1.isEven();
    val1.isOdd();
    val1.isPrime();
    isEven(val1); // <-- here is the problem.
}
```

`static` methods are not like free methods. You still need to invoke them with a class, or through an instance of that class.

E.g.:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyInteger val1 = new MyInteger(2);
    int val = 2;

    MyInteger.isEven(val1);
    val1.isEven(val1);

    MyInteger.isEven(val);
    val1.isEven(val);
}
```

Comment: Yes this worked. Thank you very much. That also explains why the isEven static method worked with just isEven if the main method was under the MyInteger class.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues here. They're explained in the comments but I'll list them here:

- I don't see a constructor in the post (at the time of writing this)
- Your main() method is in the same java file, but not the same class. They are two very different things.

  ```
  public class MyInteger {
      // Not included in post
      private int value;
      // Not included in post
      public MyInteger(int i) {
          value = i;
      }

      public boolean isEven() {
          if (this.value % 2 == 0) {
              System.out.println(value + " is an even number.");
              return true;
          } else {
              System.out.println(value + " is not an even number.");
              return false;
          }
      }

      public static boolean isEven(int value) {
          if (value % 2 == 0) {
              System.out.println(value + " is an even number.");
              return true;
          } else {
              System.out.println(value + " is not an even number.");
              return false;
          }
      }

      public static boolean isEven(MyInteger value) {
          if (value.value % 2 == 0) {
              System.out.println(value.value + " is an even number.");
              return true;
          } else {
              System.out.println(value.value + " is not an even number.");
              return false;
          }
      }

  }

  class testMyInteger {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          MyInteger val1 = new MyInteger(2);
          int val = 2;
          //System.out.println("The value of this object is " + val1.getValue()); // mispelled here, Not declared anyways
          val1.isEven();
          // these are not declared
          //val1.isOdd();
          //val1.isPrime();

          // Not inside of the 'MyInteger class, therefor not able to be called without static reference of MyInteger.isEvent
          //isEven(val1);
          MyInteger(val1);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: @GhostCat That better?

Comment: I don't think I'm overriding anything in this exercise though. All three isEven methods are writing in one class (MyInteger), then I'm only running them in a testApp class.

Comment: Opps misinterpreted the title. Gimme a second.

Comment: I do have all the constructors I need in my actual program. I just didn't add them in here because I was only having an issue with the isEven static methods. If I have the main method in a different class, shouldn't the static methods still work? My instanced isEven method is able to run in main method in another class but the static methods will not run.